# Query to check the table is temporal

Tags: sql-server

how to check if the table is temporal from c#?
How to build the query. I need to get into a variable whether a table is versioned.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT t.name, t.history_table_id, t.temporal_type, t.temporal_type_desc
FROM sys.tables t
```

The `t.temporal_type` / `temporal_type_desc` will show you whether or not the table is "temporal-enabled", and if it is, `history_table_id` will give you the `table_id` for the history table.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`OBJECTPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.YourTable'), 'TableTemporalType');
```

Which returns

- 0 = non-temporal table
- 1 = history table for system-versioned table
- 2 = system-versioned temporal table

Or `NULL` if no such table that you have permissions to see.