# System Versioned Table check schema from sys.tables

Tags: sql-server

How to check if a table has versioning enabled by specifying not only the table name but also the schema.

I use:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables 
           WHERE NAME = 'tablename' 
             AND temporal_type = 2) 
    SELECT 1 AS TABLE_EXIST 
ELSE 
    SELECT 0 AS TABLE_EXIST
```

Regards

Comment: My answer to your other question does that https://stackoverflow.com/a/69402523/73226 the example `dbo.YourTable` includes the schema

Answer (score 2):

You can JOIN `sys.schemas` and filter on the `name` column from both tables:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE temporal_type = 2
    AND s.name = 'schemaname'
    AND t.name = 'tablename'
)
    SELECT 1 AS TABLE_EXIST
ELSE
    SELECT 0 AS TABLE_EXIST;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SCHEMA_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/schema-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, which exists to simplify queries like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM SYS.tables 
WHERE 
NAME = 'tablename' 
and schema_id = schema_id('dbo')
and temporal_type = 2
```

Comment: Ah yeah... I do this so infrequently I always forget about those functions.